# ng-options taking value from 0,1,2...., instead of using Id given in option

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have data like this

```
localItems = 
     [{Id: 234565, Name: "My Class"}, 
      {Id: 871243, Name: "Class 321"}];
```

I am using this in template,

```
ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in localItems"//used to work previously
```

My angularJs version is `1.2.15`

What i want:

```
<option value="234565">My Class</option>
<option value="871243">Class 321</option>
```

What i am getting:

```
<option value="0">My Class</option>
<option value="1">Class 321</option>
```

It worked every time, I don't understand why is it not working now

Is it because Id value's are large?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have the property `value` assigned to the right ID use `track by`:

```
ng-options="item.Id as item.Name for item in localItems track by item.Id"
```

but ng-model will be assigned the right value anyway

Working JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KN9xx/20/

Comment: It is not displaying the Name in the select box :(

Answer (score 0):

The correct value based on `item.Id` is resolved by angular, regardless of each `options`'s `value` in the generated element. Check the variable assigned as `ng-model` and it will have the correct value.

Comment: i am getting the value in the model, but it doesn't display the label in select box, for the corresponding value in model